# How read var in list in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How do I get the value of the variable "price" in this compound dictionary?

```
{"coins":[{"id":"bitcoin","icon":"https://static.coinstats.app/coins/Bitcoin6l39t.png","name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","rank":1,"price":47281.470468725514}]}
```

Comment: Use `your_dict["coins"][0]["price"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first item in the list:

```
>>> coins = {"coins":[{"id":"bitcoin","icon":"https://static.coinstats.app/coins/Bitcoin6l39t.png","name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","rank":1,"price":47281.470468725514}]}
>>> coins.get('coins')[0].get('price')
47281.470468725514
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the dict you shared, you can get the value for key price like this,

```
d = {"coins":[{"id":"bitcoin","icon":"https://static.coinstats.app/coins/Bitcoin6l39t.png","name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","rank":1,"price":47281.470468725514}]}

print(d['coins'][0]['price']) # 47281.470468725514
```